# Pearl: How can I get compressed data that zlib understands

Tags: programming-pearls

I'm trying to create a zipped file in Pearl that can be consumed and deflated in an IPad application using zlib. The current zip modules in Pearl (i.e. IO::Compress::Zip ) seems to output incorrect data for the zlib to understand. I'm using z_stream strm on the C side to deflate. On thing I've noticed when using inflate in the application, is that the output looks like hex text. On the Pearl side it is non text.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I needed to use IO::Compress::Deflate.